# How to retrieve the value from array and compare each of them with column value?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrapping

I want to retrieve the values from array `$_POST["entry_of_group"]` and match *every value contained by array with database column value.*
I.e. if an array has 3 values, then I have to fetch all the rows which contain these three values.

```
<?php
session_start();
$name =$_SESSION['name'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
include("database.php");
        $run = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from users where id='$id' AND name='$name' "); 
        $user = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
        $subject_id = $user['subject_id'];
        $user_name = $user['name'];
        $run1 = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from subject where sub_id='$subject_id'");
        $subject = mysqli_fetch_array($run1);
        $subject_name = $subject['sub_name'];
        if(isset($_POST["entry_of_group"]) && !empty($_POST["entry_of_group"])){    
        // $_POST["entry_of_group"] is an array
        $all_chapters = var_dump($_POST["chapter"]);  // I want to match each and every value of var_dump array with the tuple by following query.

        $query = $conn->query("select * from `question` where question_type_id =".$_POST['entry_of_group']." AND chapter_id LIKE '%$all_chapters%' ");
        $rowCounts = $query->num_rows;    
        if($rowCounts > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select Questions</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 

            echo '<option value="'.$row['q_id'].'">'.$row['q_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Question not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: i have an array named $_POST["entry_of_group"] and i have to match all the values contain by array with database tuple. problem is that i does not get desired answer.

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) are useful advices for non-English speakers.